# Building multiple "things" on wercker

Tags: wercker

We are trying to migrate a project that is currently build on Jenkins to Wercker:

We have a Play Framework (2.4.x) application that makes have use of [multi-module architecture](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SBTSubProjects). To be more specific, it's quite close to that of [the Guardian](https://github.com/guardian/frontend).

Within **one Git repository**, we have the following structure:

[image: project setup]

What we did earlier was to detect where changes occurred since the last build. The result of that query may be this:

- `/app1/`
- `/app3/`
- `/app5/`

We only build those projects usually by invoking parallel and parameterized builds for each of those modules.

Is there a pattern that would allow us to keep this mechanism running on wercker?